# Convert an Object form date to interger and sample from years

Tags: python, pandas

In a date frame, I have a column called `publish_time` (e.g., 2001-07-04) in `Object` format. Say, in a new data frame, I want randomly keep (or sample) 100 rows from year 2019, 2020, and 2021. I would also like to know the number of lines in each year. Could you help me with this process? Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and we can help you.

Comment: Did my posted answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very precise and does not state your expected output. Note that it is much easier to provide you with help if you provide us with code examples and expected output.

However, here is a way how you could sample from a dataframe based on specified years. This is not a very concise version, but I believe it is easy to follow the separate steps.

```
# Some dummy dataframe with dates
data = {"date":pd.date_range("01/01/2001",periods=1000),
        "other":np.random.rand(1000)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["date"] = df["date"].astype("object") # Date is now of type object


# STEP 1: Convert to datetime
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])



# STEP 2: Sampling for specified years
sample_years = [2001, 2002]
sample_size = 100

for year in sample_years:
     smpl = df[df["date"].dt.year==year].sample(sample_size)
     data.append(smpl)

data # Contains two dataframes (one for 2001 and one for 2002 sample)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was very helpful. I will give more details in my next question.